# How to disinfect and clean a condensate water trap

Tags: hvac, cleaning, flooding

What's the best way to disinfect this water trap - some sewage backflowed into it and it has a bunch of little chambers that I can't reach with a brush.  Should I soak it in some sort of solution or just replace it?

Whatever I use it should be safe to go back into an HVAC system once it dries.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it appears to be all plastic, and it's been removed, I'd soak it in a moderately strong solution of chlorine bleach for a day or two, *per* directions on the bleach, and scrub with a bottle brush or tooth brush, *while wearing long waterproof gloves* and old, ready to be discarded, clothing.

Afterwards, **put an air-break between the trap and waste line** to prevent such back-flow in the future.